# "Save", "Cancel" etc. button not working in Joomla 3 after migrating a component

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I am migrating a component made for 2.5 to Joomla 3.4. Everything is working fine now, except one thing: the Joomla toolbar buttons do not react at all in backend. What could be wrong there? It worked fine with Joomla 2.5.

```
    // Set the toolbar
    $this->addToolBar();

    // Display the template
    parent::display($tpl);
}

/**
 * Setting the toolbar
 */

protected function addToolBar() 
    {
            JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
            $isNew = ($this->item->id == 0);

            JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? JText::_('New note') :   JText::_('Edit note'));
            JToolBarHelper::save('guestbook.save');
            JToolBarHelper::cancel('guestbook.cancel', $isNew ? 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL' : 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
    }
```

Comment: Final solution: the form **id** always has to be set to "adminForm".

Comment: i too accept with Mich.C answer it may be one of the reason it is important to have id 'adminForm'  and another reason may be js problem.System js may not loaded correctly.